# Create macOS 10.12 VM on VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

Can someone let me know how can I create a macOS 10.12 VM for VMware Fusion? I am not able to find the ISO of macOS 10.12.

In app store I am seeing *macOS High Sierra* which I am not interested in.

Environment:-

- VMware Fusion - 8.5.8
- OS in which Fusion Running - macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Fusion is able to create a macOS VM from the installer on your computer’s recovery partition, which should still have 10.12 on it. This is probably your only option until Apple makes the 10.12 installed available somehow.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/8.0/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-E6C50392-31BA-4466-9A2E-D133B48C0E8A.html